# How to get database Deletion Time?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I had used `DROP DATABASE` command to drop a database. Is there any way through which I can see the time at which the `DROP` command was executed (i.e. at what time the database got deleted)?

Can I get it by reading any SQL or Windows log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it what you need? Sql Server trace  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx UPD: looks like it's too late for this tool

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ms SQL Server 2005 or later, you can get it from the default log.

`SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)`

- Find the filename of the trc-file in the results.

`select * from fn_trace_gettable('PATH_TO_TRC_FILE',DEFAULT) where EventClass in (47) and databasename='NAME_OF_DB'`

- Replace the path to the trc-file with your path from previous command and NAME_OF_DB with the name of the database you want to know about.

[See this page for details](http://sivasql.blogspot.se/2010/07/how-to-find-who-dropped-database-is.html)

Good luck!